# Alternately glibc detected free(): invalid next size (fast)

Tags: c, malloc

Please help, I'm so new in C that I don't understand the problem
I have 3 files
main.c, set.c, set.h
in set.h

```
typedef struct Set{unsigned char array[16];
}Set;
```

in main.c
main method

```
int main
{
    int i=0;
    char *input="read_set A,0,1,2,3,4";
    char *output[LEN_ACTIONS];
    char *d=" ";

    read_input(input, output, d,0);
    char *methodName = output[0];
     printf("method name:%s\n", methodName);

    invoke_method(methodName, output);

    for(i=0; i < LEN_ACTIONS; i++)
        free(output[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

in set.c

```
void read_input(char *input,char **output, char *delimiter, int onlyNumbers)
{    
    int index =0;
    char *str =(char*)malloc(strlen(input));
    strcpy(str, input);
    char *tok=NULL;
     tok = strtok(str,delimiter);

    while(tok!=NULL)
    {
        char *dup = (char*)malloc(strlen(tok)+1);
        if(dup)
        {
            if(onlyNumbers >0)
            {
                if(is_number(tok))
                 {
                    output[index] = strcpy(dup, tok);
                    index++;
                }
            }    
            else
            {
                output[index] = strcpy(dup, tok);
                 index++;
            }    
        }

        tok = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    }
    free(str);
}
```

in main.c

```
void invoke_method(char *methodName, char **output)
{
    int i=0;
    char *d=",";
    char *groups[5];
    read_input(output[1], groups, d, 0);

    if(strcmp(methodName,"read_set") ==0)
     {
        printf("group: %s\n", groups[0]);

        d=",";
        char *numbers[MAX_IN_SET]={NULL};
        read_input(output[1], numbers, d, 1);

        if(strcmp(groups[0], "A")==0)
         {
            printf("init A set\n");
            initialize_set(&A); //initialize the array with 0
            printf("input to set\n");
            read_set(&A, numbers);
        }
        if(strcmp(groups[0], "B")==0)
         {
            initialize_set(&B);
            read_set(&B, numbers);
        }
        if(strcmp(groups[0], "C")==0)
        {
            initialize_set(&C);
            read_set(&C, numbers);
         }
        if(strcmp(groups[0], "D")==0)
        {
            initialize_set(&D);
            read_set(&D, numbers);
        }
        if(strcmp(groups[0], "E")==0)
         {
            initialize_set(&E);
            read_set(&E, numbers);
        }
    }


    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
        free(groups[i]);
 }
```

in set.c

```
void read_set(struct Set *set, char **numbers)
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i<MAX_IN_SET; i++)
    {

        if(numbers[i] != NULL && numbers[i] != '\0')
        {
             int number = atoi(numbers[i]);
            int charIndex = number/8;
            int bitIndex = number %8;
            int bitPlace = 1<<(7-bitIndex);
            unsigned char c = (unsigned char)bitPlace;
             int numberExists = c & set->array[charIndex];
            if(!numberExists)
            {
                set->array[charIndex] = c|set->array[charIndex];
                /*printf("number %d has been added\n", number);*/
             }
        }
    }
}
```

in terminal after I run this I get an error

*** glibc detected*** ./mainprog: free(): invalid next size (fast)

Thank you very much

Comment: You should take care of always properly initialise variables. Like doing for example: `char * output[LEN_ACTIONS] = {0};` and `char * groups[5] = {0};`

Answer (score 1):

At least one problem there:

```
char *str =(char*)malloc(strlen(input));
```

should be

```
char *str =(char*)malloc(strlen(input) + 1);
```

or better yet

```
char *str = strdup(input);
```

You're not allocating space for terminating 0, so following strcopy steps on the heap data structures.

Use valgrind to find more problems, if any.

Comment: I always think it's funny when people suggest the use of valgrind or gdb in situations like this.  Of course those are awesome tools but isn't figuring out how to use them is *way too hard* for someone struggling with issues on the level that OP is having?

Comment: Thank you for your help but still it's not solve my problem :( I hvaed notice that the crashes depends on the input lenth char *input="read_set A,0,1,2,3,4";

Comment: if  your input is larger than the original text the `input` variable points to,  you'll  have the same problem.

Comment: @Andrey:  there is something to what you say.  Valgrind  will point at two lines and say what's wrong though.  May be the user will have an epiphany  :-)

Answer (score 1):

A possible problem is the loop that frees the array of char*.  One of them is:

```
for(i=0; i < LEN_ACTIONS; i++)
    free(output[i]);
```

It depends on the input, but if there are not LEN_ACTIONS entries allocated in that array, then the free call is likely invalid because the array was not initialized to zeros (null).  One possibility might be to initialize the array up front (because passing NULL to free is valid).  Use something like this prior to its use:

```
memset(output, 0, sizeof(output));
```

The same potential problem exists with `groups` inside `invoke_method`.